# Android studio's allocation tracker graphical view

Tags: android, android-studio, memory-profiling

According the Android's blog:
http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2015/07/get-your-hands-on-android-studio-13.html

There should be a new visual way to diagnose memory allocations (AKA sunburst view).
After updating to Studio 1.3 we can't find any way to switch the memory allocator view and nothing new in DDMS's memory profiler as well.

How can we access this new view?

Comment: Start allocation tracking, track up to your desire, stop it to reveal the allocation view and click the menu at the left top corner

Comment: Thanks, I found it eventually in Android's docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. At the bottom of the android studio screen, click "Android Monitor".
2. Switch to the "Memory" tab (alongside the default logcat tab)
3. Click start recording (last icon on the left side).
4. Click stop recording.

It will take a few seconds to analyse and eventually load the memory view with options to select between available charts and views

Comment: thanks, i had a link-only answer to my own question that was deleted, the docs that show this solution are at https://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html#heap-dump